# retrieving key value pairs from a JSON object - Node JS

Tags: ajax, node.js

From the front end I am passing a `JSON array` to my `Node JS` backend. Now, I need to retrieve the `JSON array` and read its `key-value` pair and print it out in the `console`. How can I do this.

Code is given as follows:

JQUERY

```
$( "#send" ).submit(function( event ) {    
  var dict = {};
  $("input[name=name]").each(function (i) {
    dict[$(this).val()] = $('input[name=age]').eq(i).val();
  });

  someObject=JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2);

 $.ajax({
   url: "food/newpage",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: { dataobj: someObject },
 });
});
```

NODE JS

```
router.post('/newpage', function (req, res, next) {    
  console.log('print ' + req.body.dataobj);

  for(var attributename in req.body.dataobj){
    console.log(attributename+": "+req.body.dataobj[attributename]);
  }

  res.render('food/newpage');
});
```

When I printed the `req.body.dataobj` I get the following output:

```
{
  "sam": "five",
  "Alex": "fifteen",   
  "Matt": "Two",   
}
```

My question is: I need to retrieve the JSON array and print it in a `console.log` as `key is equal to the name` and `value is equal to the age`. How can I do this ?

**OUTPUT - Update**

> key= 0 and value ={ 0={ key= 1 and value =
>
> 1=
>
> key= 2 and value =  2=  key= 3 and value =  3=  key= 4 and value ="
>   4=" key= 5 and value =s 5=s key= 6 and value =f 6=f key= 7 and value
>   =d 7=d key= 8 and value =s 8=s key= 9 and value =f 9=f key= 10 and value =" 10=" key= 11 and value =: 11=: key= 12 and value =  12=  key=
>   13 and value =" 13=" key= 14 and value =a 14=a key= 15 and value =d
>   15=d key= 16 and value =f 16=f key= 17 and value =d 17=d key= 18 and
>   value =" 18=" key= 19 and value =
>
> 19=
>
> key= 20 and value =} 20=}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,I didn't tried but you will get the result.

Jquery

```
$( "#send" ).submit(function( event ) {    
var dict = {};
$("input[name=name]").each(function (i) {
 dict[$(this).val()] = $('input[name=age]').eq(i).val();
});

$.ajax({
 url: "food/newpage",
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "json",
 data: { dataobj: someObject },
});
});
```

Node js

```
router.post('/newpage', function (req, res, next) {

console.log('print ' + req.body.dataobj);

for(var k in req.body.dataobj){
console.log("key= "+ k + " and value ="+ req.body.dataobj[k] );
console.log(k + "="+ req.body.dataobj[k]);
 }

res.render('food/newpage');

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Can you help me. I get `key= undefined and value =undefined`

Comment: @IIIep, You had a problem in for loop,its not fetching the result so i changed that for loop syntax and display the data,so now you can get the proper result.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It retrieves character by character. See my question Above I have edited the question with the output I am getting for your solution.

Comment: The code you updated 8 mins ago ? If so it doesn't work. I have updated my question with the output I got for it.

Comment: @IIIep Your Json object is not in proper format,it should be like { sam: "five",Alex: "fifteen",  Matt: "Two"} ,key should not be enclosed between " "  parenthesis.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get it done that way. I have been stuck with this problem for days now.

Comment: @IIIep, you have to  parse the stringifyd json array so you will get proper formated json object because you had stringify the json array in ajax cal.I update the code,just check

Comment: I get this syntax error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)` for `JSON.parse`. Why ? Please help

Comment: @lllep,then just try JSON.stringify(req.body.dataobj) instead of JSON.parse(req.body.dataobj)

Comment: Now, I dont get that error but then, It prints character by character instead of Key and Value.

Answer (score 0):

Before using, You have to parse dataobj as json object as bellow

```
router.post('/newpage', function (req, res, next) {

console.log('print ' + req.body.dataobj);

**req.body.dataobj = JSON.parse(req.body.dataobj)**

for(var attributename in req.body.dataobj){
  console.log("key= "+ attributename.name + " and value ="+ attributename.age);
  console.log(attributename.name + "="+ attributename.age  +);
 }
res.render('food/newpage');

});
```

Comment: I've got a hunch that there's `body-parser` express middleware in play. It parses incoming request bodies before user handlers.

Comment: Take a look **dataobj** key containing string value which stringed by JSON.stringify where middleware will not parse the dataobj key as object.

Comment: Now i get this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`. how can i solve this ?

Comment: Try by removing JSON.stringify & JSON.parse from both sides

Answer (score 0):

You could get the desired entry (e.g. for "Alex") by indexing the object literal using the brackets notation

```
var age = req.body.dataobj["Alex"]
if (age > ...) { ... }
```

and then check if the age meets your criteria.

Just to correct you a tiny bit: you're actually sending an *object literal* (`{ a: b }`) to the backend, not an array (`[a, b]`).

Comment: I want to access from the index.